# Sign In with Google - Console.log

Tags: google-signin

I'm trying to use this new example for the new Sign In with Google since oAuth will be retired in 2023.   Question is, how do I pass this value console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email); to a hidden html field ?    I was able to do this with the current oAuth Java funstion but can't seem to pass the value with this new version of the code.

decodeJwtResponse() is a custom function defined by you -  could be what I'm missing.  I would like to keep this entire function in java script if possible.  I am lost

```
    <div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
</div>
<script>
  function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
     // decodeJwtResponse() is a custom function defined by you
     // to decode the credential response.
     const responsePayload = decodeJwtResponse(response.credential);

     console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
     console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
     console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
     console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
     console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
     console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can decode the token with https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode, or see how it's done in `lib/index.js` if it's doesn't support not using NPM. Btw oauth is not being deprecated, perhaps you mean the older web SDK library for handling it/rendering a button. Actually oauth doesn't need any special UI libraries, in fact for best security all the oauth handling is better off on a server anyway

Comment: yes, your are correct. I meant the web SDK. ok so it looks like I need to install jwt-decode package manager.  I'm using asp.net.  I can get everything else to work except for getting the users email address.  Thanks

Comment: I can't even seem top get the token to decode it.

Comment: You are able to read everything except email on `responsePayload`? For email you need an additional scope: `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"`

Comment: my issue is, I do not know how to create the decodeJwtResponse function to get the token values.  I was able to find the token using fidler and decode it at jwt.io but that's as far as I can get.

Comment: You need to pass a base64 url decoded version of it into `JSON.parse(decodedResult)` as per jwt-decode - https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/master/lib/base64_url_decode.js

Comment: @Dominic scopes are no longer used with the new library. OAuth2, scopes and access tokens are unnecessary. Email is contained within the JWT as a field.

Comment: I love it. So we have to completely update our Google Button SDK and then, half way through the instructions they just expect you to go away and work out how to decrypt something else using ANOTHER library your software has to depend on.  They couldn't just bundle it in with their own JS?

Software development in today's world is spend mostly upgrading all the 3rd party libraries you downloaded. Then, users complain your pages don't work on their mobile because they have to download 2MB of libraries so you can us 2% of the tools inside.

It's all a massive mess.

Answer (score 9):

Try This Native Javascript Code.

```js
function decodeJwtResponse (token) 
{
    var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
    return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));

    return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To decode the token you need to Base64 URL decode the message and parse it back into an object with `JSON.parse`, which is what [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) does.

If you're not using a bundler with NPM you can import it:

```js
console.log(jwt_decode('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode.js"></script>
```

Or as an ES6 module:

```html
<script type="module">
// Or https://unpkg.com/jwt-decode/build/jwt-decode.esm.js
import jwtDecode from 'https://esm.run/jwt-decode';

console.log(jwtDecode('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'))
</script>
```

Comment: ok, thank you....  so, this part right here `console.log(jwtDecode('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c'))`  how do I point that to the google token ?

Comment: I can't seem to decode the token.  I can create an alert and view response.credential , just cannot seem to decode it.

Comment: <script type="module">

import jwtDecode from 'https://esm.run/jwt-decode';

function handleCredentialResponse(response) {

const responsePayLoad = jwtDecode(response.credential);

console.log("ID: " + responsePayLoad.sub);
console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayLoad.name);
console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayLoad.given_name);
console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayLoad.family_name);
console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayLoad.picture);
console.log("Email: " + responsePayLoad.email);

alert(responsePayLoad.email);
                    }
</script>

Comment: decoded_jwt = jwtDecode('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c')
console.log(decoded_jwt.email)

Comment: perfect answer this is what i am looking

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it manually using https://jwt.io/ with algorithm RS256

And programmatically using jose library https://github.com/panva/jose

```
import * as jose from 'jose'
const claims = jose.decodeJwt(token)
console.log(claims)
```

The result is the same as in the documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#credential

You should verify the JWT (public keys, issuer, audience, issuer and expiration date), jose has a function to decode and verify called jwtVerify
https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/main/docs/functions/jwt_verify.jwtVerify.md#readme